# How to recursive delete btrfs snapshot?

Tags: delete, btrfs, snapshot

How can I delete a snapshot  that contain in itself other snapshots? The normal `sudo btrfs subvolume delete` will give a error.

Comment: How do you create your snapshots? I put my snapshots in subdirectories of the snapshotted volume and can delete them the standard way without a problem. I must say that snapshots don't reappear recursively at mine though.

Comment: I do the same thing but I want to delete the upper snapshot

Comment: You might be running into [this](http://blog.lyte.id.au/2013/03/08/deleting-an-apt-snapshot-btrfs-subvolume-is-hard/). How are your subvolumes/snapshots arranged?

Comment: The output of `btrfs subvolume list` would be nice in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive subvolume deletion (snapshots are just read-only subvolumes) is not yet available in btrfs-tools.  In order to delete the top-level, you must first delete the lower levels.

You can get a list of the subvolumes with the `btrfs subvolume list` command.  The -o option should let you filter the results to just the ones you care about, but feel free to experiment.  You should then be able to go down the list and delete all the sub-subvolumes, after which you should be able to delete the toplevel subvolume, and then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `btrfs subvolume list` hates sanity.  Here's a prototype script.

It works on a subvolume in the current directory, assumes `tmp` doesn't exist, has worryingly unsafe behaviour on "special characters" (`|` or regular expression characters in **parent** directories), has undiscovered bugs and no comments.  The regex issue should probably be avoided by re-writing to use bash string matching instead of `sed`.  If the output of `btrfs subvolume list` changes at some point it will eat you.

```
#!/bin/sh
# DISCLAIMER: see above
set -e

function my_ls_pwd() {
    btrfs sub list -o "$1" | cut -d " " -f 9
}

btrfs sub create tmp
btrfs sub create tmp/tmp
BTRFS_PWD=$(my_ls_pwd tmp | sed -e 's|tmp/tmp$||')
btrfs sub del tmp/tmp
btrfs sub del tmp

# `btrfs sub list` shows full path within the FS;
# we want path relative to the working directory
function my_ls() {
    my_ls_pwd $1 | sed -e "s|^$BTRFS_PWD||"
}

# Recursive subvolume delete
function my_deltree() {
    my_ls "$1" | while read i; do
        my_deltree "$i"
    done
    btrfs sub del "$1"
}
my_deltree $1
```